# Django: How to use same abstract class twice with same fields but different names?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have an abstract model called `Address` with fields such as `address_line`, `postcode` etc.

Now I want to create a model `Person` which has multiple types of addresses like `residential_address`, `office_address` etc. How can I achieve that in Django?

My `Address` model:

```
class Address(Model):

    address_line_one = CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=255,
    )

    address_postcode = CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=50,
        validators=POSTCODE_VALIDATORS
    )

    class Meta(GlobalMeta):
        abstract = True
```

My `Person` class:

```
class Person(Address, Model):
    name = CharField(
        blank = True
        max_length = True
    )
    class Meta:
    app_label = "person"
    
)
```

`forms`

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = []
        widgets = {}
```

`form.html`

```
<div>
    {% form.name %}
</div>
```

Comment: Your example code maybe is incorrect please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not inherit from `Address` in your `Person` class. The basic premise of inheritance is an "Is a" relationship, i.e. your code ends up saying "`Person` *is an* `Address`" which is wrong! What you want instead is an [Aggregation](https://www.google.com/search?q=OOPS+aggregation) in terms of Object Oriented Programming. You can do this in databases / Django models by using foreign keys.

In Django you can use the [`ForeignKey` [Django doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field to model such relationships:

```py
from django.db import models


class Address(Model):

    address_line_one = CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=255,
    )

    address_postcode = CharField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=50,
        validators=POSTCODE_VALIDATORS
    )

    class Meta(GlobalMeta):
        # This should not be abstract
        # abstract = True


class Person(Model):
    name = CharField(
        blank = True
        max_length = 50 # This must be a number
    )
    residential_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='residing_people'
    )
    office_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='office_people'
    )
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = "person"
```

Comment: I can't actually make `Address` non abstract as it is being used throughout the code. Also, I dont want to create a table for `Address`

Comment: @Rachit It seems you need to research a bit on Database normalization and OOPS concepts as you are _misusing_ these concepts very badly. A new table for Addresses is in fact a __good design__ as you reuse code that way.

Comment: I get your point but this is how the old code base is setup. Unfortunately, the company doesn't have budget to migrate the legacy code and I will have to work on what is given